# Storing location information in SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database of the road networks of a city with distance information in it.

I've 50 major places selected in the city and each place is connected to another place in some way through the road network. Like distance between Place A and place B is 5km, B and C is 10km and A and C is 15km.

I need to store the distance information systematically so that when a query is run like from A to B or From A to any place that lies within these 50 places.

Is there any simpler way to do it other than creating rows like A to B, A to C, A to D and so on?

Comment: I've no knowledge of using it (seen it mentioned on the SQLite mailing list) but you might look at [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) which I believe extends SQLite with spatial/geographic features.